# JSON Extract JSON in Metabase SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, metabase

i have this table

| id | status | outgoing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | paid | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing"} |
| 2 | unpaid | {"old.a945248027_14454878":"cancelled"} |

i am trying to extract the value after underscore i.e 14454878

i tried extracting the keys using this query on metabase

```
select id, outgoing,
       substring(key from '_([^_]+)$') as key
from table,
cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(outgoing) as j(key);
```

but i keep getting the error

ERROR: function jsonb_object_keys(json) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 129

Please help

Comment: Your column is defined as `json` but you are using a function that expects `jsonb`. Use `json_object_keys()` instead (but the column should really be changed to `jsonb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is defined as json but i used a function that expects jsonb.
so i changed Use jsonb_object_keys() to jsonb_object_keys()

```
select id, outgoing,
       substring(key from '_([^_]+)$') as key
from table,
cross join lateral json_object_keys(outgoing) as j(key);
```